# Custom artisan commands with multiple 'methods' (in the style of migrate:install etc)

Tags: laravel-4

I'm creating a custom artisan command (foo) for my Laravel 4 application. I can see from the [userguide](http://laravel.com/docs/commands) how to accept arguments and options, e.g.

```
php artisan foo argument --option
```

But what if I want to have a custom artisan command that has many 'methods', in the same style as some built-in artisan commands, e.g. *migrate:install*?. I want to make something like:

```
php artisan foo:baz argument --option
```

What is the recommended way to implement different methods based on the **:** colon separator? All I've found to try so far is to make an entirely new artisan command for each 'method'. Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to set the name:

```
protected $name = 'foo:baz';
```

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, you **do** need a new Artisan command (or rather a class) for each method. However all you have to do is register each file in `app/Console/Kernel.php`, if you decide to change the syntax later than Laravel will pick it up any changes to `$signature` automatically without you needing to rename any files.

For the Laravel example you mention, *migrate*, there's a directory with a separate file for each command name (including the one that has no colon):

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations

- migrate -> MigrateCommand.php
- migrate:install -> InstallCommand.php
- migrate:refresh -> RefreshCommand.php
- migrate:reset -> ResetCommand.php
- migrate:rollback -> RollbackCommand.php
- migrate:status -> StatusCommand.php

If you have code you want to reuse ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) note that  if you examine the above commands, some of them use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), e.g. *Illuminate\Console\ConfirmableTrait* – which contains a  *confirmToProceed()* method which, if it's running in production, will ask the user if they really want to continue.

NB: the Artisan syntax changed in 5.1, from `$name` (with a rather complicated way of specifying arguments and options) to the much simpler  `$signature`, it's backwards compatible. [More info](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/creating-artisan-commands-with-the-new-simpler-syntax-in-laravel-5.1)